# Trying to deploy site on Netlify, link is not working

Tags: python, html, netlify

I was trying to manually deploy an html file on Netlify. Although it uploads successfully, the link created is always broken. What should i do?

I tried to upload the folder multiple times to no avail. I expected the site to run the simple HTML site i had to write for an Intro to Programming class.

Answer (score 0):

You may have already tried this but Netlify needs an `index.html` file to display as the root page if you are manually uploading HTML files.

If your document has a different name (e.g., `mypage.html`), try naming it as `index.html` and reuploading it on https://app.netlify.com/drop.